# How to Resize Video 720:1280 Bigger Height, Width and Crop To 1280:720 using ffmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg, scale

I have video Original size 720:1280 and want to convert it to size 1280:720 but before converting I want to increase it bigger first.

[image: I have a video original size 720:1280 Below]

Using Code Below, I can resize the video to 1280:720 but it is not the result that I want.

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -filter_complex scale=1280:720:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease,pad=1280:720:-1:-1:color=black output.mp4
```

[image]

This is what I want to get. Please Help Me To solve the problem. Your answer is so important to me.
Thank you so much. I am waiting your reply.

[image: This is what I want to get]

Comment: @llogan, Can you help me?

Comment: In your 2nd image, you're cropping the video first. To be able to answer, we need to know how much you wish to crop.

Comment: @Gyan, I crop it 720:824 brother.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apply the crop first.

`-filter_complex crop=720:824,scale=1280:720:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease,pad=1280:720:-1:-1:color=black`

Comment: Now my problem is solved. Thank you for valuable answers, brother.